# What the different task array and task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Given snippet code

```
var Task1 = DoAsync(0);
var Task2 = DoAsync(1);

await Task.WhenAll(Task1,Task2);
```

and

```
Task[] TaskArray = new Task[2];
TaskArray[0] = DoAsync(0);
TaskArray[1] = DoAsync(1);
await Task.WhenAll(TaskArray);
```

May I know, any different how the task will be execute from the code I give it?

It is true the TaskArray will be running at the same time?

Comment: Look up the `params` keyword

Comment: There is no difference - the compiler will convert the two parameters to an array.

Comment: "It is true the TaskArray will be running at the same time?" not necessarily - you just kick them both off at (roughly) the same time.  There's no guarantee that they both run concurrently.

Comment: Ok now I understand how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> May I know, any different how the task will be execute from the code I give it?

Your two code snippets are identical. A `params` method can be called either way -- if you pass the arguments, as in your first example, all it does is just creates an array, as you did in your second example.

> It is true the TaskArray will be running at the same time?

Not necessarily.  Asynchronous code is not necessarily *parallel* or *concurrent*.  All we know is that we have two operations that will produce a result later. There is no requirement whatsoever that they do so by running on two different processors at the same time, or on one processor on different threads.